# Rails 6 - Phusion error for uninitialized constant URI::Generic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, uri, phusion, uninitialized-constant

I'm using rails `6.0.3.4`, `ruby 2.5.0` with `nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`. Everything was fine until I did a new deploy *(using capistrano)* and suddenly I'm getting `Could not spawn process for application /home/deploy/appname/current: The application encountered the following error: uninitialized constant URI::Generic (NameError)`.

I have required these in `application.rb` *(also tested requiring in the model)* with no luck:

```
require 'uri'
require "uri/generic"
```

At this point, I'm not sure what could be wrong.

Thanks in advance if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed it was a bug between `Rails` and `Ruby`, so I upgraded my `Rails` to the current stable version as well as upgraded my `ruby` version.